# Combining/simplifying two promises being called in multiple functions

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, promise, ionic3

I'm starting to get used to promise driven code, but I've found myself repeating bits of code extremely often. In particular, I have an Ionic app where I make many API calls, and prior to running the call I check if there is an Internet connection and if the user is authenticated. Each of these functions is structured like this:

```
  noteCreate(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise (resolve => {
      this.connCheck()
      .then(success => {
        if (success) {
          this.authCheck('Please login first!')
          .then(success => {
            if (success) {

              // API CALL

            }
          });
        }
      })
    });
  }
```

I'm hoping there's a way that I could possible decorate my API calls or condense these two checks into something simple and not so bulky/repetitive, but I'm not sure how I should go about this.

I look for both `connCheck` and `authCheck` to return `true` to proceed with the API calls. I do want to keep these functions separate because in some cases, I only need to check for the connection, and in others only for authentication (locally).

```
  connCheck(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.myURL() + '/heartbeat/', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          resolve(true);
        },
        (err) => {
          resolve(false);
        }
      );
    })
  }

  authCheck(message: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.storage.get('user').then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code contains antipatterns that sometimes are referred as [nested promisees](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/#nested-promises:8f173b15e2d19515fdc8ce931ae539c0) antipattern and promise construction antipattern (a close relative of [deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)).

There's already a promise that can be chained. There's no need to create another one, `new Promise (resolve => ...)`.

Promises require limited levels of nesting. All promises should be chained. If a promise is just hanging around and isn't returned, this is a mistake.

If there are multiple conditions, promise chain can be flattened by breaking it with a rejection:

```
  noteCreate(): Promise<any> {
    const alreadyAuthorized = new Error();

    return this.connCheck()
    .then(success => {
      if (success)
        return this.authCheck('Please login first!')
      else
        throw alreadyAuthorized ;
    })
    .then(success => {
       if (success) {
         return ... // API CALL
       }
    ))
    .catch(err => {
      if (err === alreadyAuthorized)
        return;
      else
        throw err;
    });
  }
```

A more convenient way is to switch to `async..await` because it was introduced to provide syntactic sugar for promise control flow. A rejection can be rewritten to early return from the function:

```
  async noteCreate(): Promise<any> {
    if (!(await this.connCheck()))
      return;

    if (!(await this.authCheck('Please login first!')))
      return;

    return ... // API CALL        
  }
```

Using `this.http.get(...).subscribe(...)` in conjunction with promises is a mistake. Observables can be easily converted to promises and back:

```
  connCheck(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.http.get(this.myURL() + '/heartbeat/', {responseType: 'text'})
    .map(Boolean) // maps data to a boolean
    .toPromise();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of promises is to be able to chain logic. If any part of the chain fails, you can catch it at the end. You could simply do:

```
return this.connCheck()
  .then(() => this.authCheck())
  .then(() => {
     ... API call...
  })
  .catch(error => ...)
```

The catch will be triggered if any of the promises are rejected.

You should probably put the catch at the very end of your promise chain.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't same thing as original code. In case `this.authCheck()` fails the check, it results in resolved value, not .in a rejection

Comment: Definitely a helpful response, but @estus raised the right point. It wouldn't work the same way I need it to.